# How do I round decimals to the nearest 0.05?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like the 2nd decimal to round to a zero or a 5. The ROUND() function in excel is not capable of this(or so far as I can tell).
Any ideas how I would get results as in the following example?

```
0.63 = 0.60
0.58 = 0.6
1.21 = 1.20
```

Comment: Use the `LEFT()` function. Ex. `=LEFT(A1,3)`

Comment: `=ROUND(A1*20,0)/20`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`MROUND`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/mround-function-c299c3b0-15a5-426d-aa4b-d2d5b3baf427) to specify the multiple you want to round to:

```
=MROUND(A1,0.05)
```

[image]

Comment: This is definitely the function you should use!

Answer (score 1):

```
=MROUND(A1,.05)
```

Not sure if you mistyped that first rounding example but the MROUND function should get your job done.